# Plotting error values in MATLAB for highly dense temporal data

Tags: matlab, plot

I know that we can plot error values in MATLAB using errorbar.m
However, I need to know if it possible to plot error values as a "faded tape" on the data so the actual data values are still visible. As you can see from the plot below generated using errorbar.m, the data line is overwhelmed by the error bars.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `patch`, with transparency to see the other data series underneath:

```
xdata = [...];
value =[...];
errors = [...];

patch_x = [xdata fliplr(xdata)];
patch_y = [(value + errors) fliplr(value - errors)];

figure;
hold on;
patch(patch_x,patch_y,'facealpha',0.5,'edgecolor','none');
plot(xdata,value)
```

Comment: thanks for the response @tmpearce! It works really well. Also I added the color input to patch.m in your response to avoid getting an error.